# Sorttable ul li get order

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html is like this

```
<ul>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>
       <ul>
          <li>...</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

This is just a example, a `ul` can contain many `li` but the max depth is `ul li ul` like in example

I am using [JqueryUI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) to sort this `li` I want to get the sort order of the `li` to store it in database so that user dont have to sort each time.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to bind the "sortupdate" event which you can use to update your database. The next time the page loads you have to sort the items serverside.

EDIT:

The following will bind the sortupdate event and post it to /story/reorder (www.asdf.com/sort/reorder?ids=somevalue&oldIds=anothervalue). That page will store it in the database.

You probably have to add another variable to pass the userid of the person who logged in.

```
$("#sortable").bind('sortupdate', function(event, ui) {
    var ids = $("#sortable").sortable('serialize').toString();
    $.post('/story/reorder', {ids: ids, oldIds: idsOldOrder}, function(data) {
        // nothing special
        window.alert(data);
    });
    idsOldOrder = ids;
});
```

Source: http://www.gridshore.nl/2009/09/14/creating-a-sortable-list-of-items-using-jquery/

Comment: Any example usage? `update: function(event, ui) { ......  }` I saw this but unable to understand application, new to javascript.